# share excel file from one application to another application

Tags: ios

I have added export UTI in shareDocument Application

[image]

Another application which will import excel file

[image]

Now while sharing from shareDocument Application i don't see my application name in the list. So whats wrong here if somebody can share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly need to add **Document Type**. Here its for **xls and xlsx format document**

[image]

Now you need specify **Import UTI** or **Export UTI**

[image]

For more reference check [How do I get my application to show up in the “Open in...” menu on iOS for a specific document type?](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1587/_index.html)

For All [System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html)

**Note** : To get exact UTI for specific file format :

```
NSArray *extensionArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"doc", @"docx", @"ppt", @"pptx", @"xls", @"xlsx",@"mp3",@"mp4",@"rft",@"rtf",@"pages",@"key",@"numbers",nil];

for (int i=0; i<[extensionArray count]; i++) {
    NSString *fileExtension = [extensionArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *utiString = (__bridge NSString *)UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension,(__bridge CFStringRef)fileExtension,NULL);
    NSLog(@"Extension: %@ UTI:%@",fileExtension,utiString);
}
```